Rustdoc: Add non-rust source file
I'd like to provide my Pest grammar file in documentation generated by rustdoc. All .rs files get their corresponding html in doc/src/cratename, but I cannot found any option to add files with other extensions. Is there any way?

Do you want to parse a pest grammar file and add doc comments to the documentation or do you just want the whole grammar in the documentation?

I'd just want to have the full file, same way all .rs files are attached and browsable.

You can do #[doc = include_str!("../path/to/file")], if that's any help.  See https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/write-documentation/the-doc-attribute.html#the-doc-attribute
